# Access 2019 Query through 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Table A

```
ID      Name        Pay     Colleage
1       aaa       15,000        1
2       bbb       25,000        2
```

Table B : Deduction Money

```
ID      Min      Max     Colleage1   Colleage2   Colleage3  Colleage4
1     10,001   20,000      1,000       2,000       3,000      4,000
2     20,001   30,000      2,000       3,000       4,000      5,000
```

I have to take each employee's deduction money in Table B.

Given Table B says, aaa's deduction money will be 1,000.

Because its range of pay is between 10,001~20,000
and it has 1 colleage.

So if i follow it on Table B. I can find the amount is ***1,000***.

As same way, bbb will be ***3,000***.

But I can't get the proper value.

I want query syntax to use for access 2019.

So help me pz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables and use [`CHOOSE()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4) to select the correct deduction:

```
SELECT a.*, CHOOSE(a.Colleage, b.Colleage1, b.Colleage2, b.Colleage3, b.Colleage4) AS Deduction
FROM TableA AS a INNER JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.Pay >= b.Min AND a.Pay <= b.Max
```

Comment: Thank you so much, But b.id and a.id could not be the same. there is no comparison point (FK) to connect each tables. Table B is just for search and get.

Comment: I have learned precious one from you..so excited...Thank you so much again.